# Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

When I ran the Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb -url "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Test" -IncludeAll I am getting below error message in Powershell 7.3.

Get-PnPSiteScriptFromWeb: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Actually I am trying to add Sharepoint site temaplate in the orgnization template for that when i try to run those commands I am getting bad request message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to do a troubleshooting:

1.Check if the Site URL is correct

2.Check the PS version using $PSversionTable

3.Re-install SharePoint Online Management Shell using the command: `Install-Module -Name Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell`

If you are using Powershell v7.0 ,you can reference this similar issue:

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2595